# Prevent spark jdbc write from changing the table structure

Tags: apache-spark, jdb

I am using spark df write to write to oracle table -

When the data is written the underlying oracle table structure is changed by spark

```
df.write.
                  mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).
                  jdbc(targetJdbcUrl, targetTable, targetProps)
```

Is there a way to prevent spark from modifying the table structure?

For example -

> source_desc varchar(200)

get converted to

```
source_desc varchar(255)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
 mode(SaveMode.Append)
```

Did the trick.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19784837)

Comment: That is the correct answer. (Use SaveMode.Append instead of SaveMode.Overwrite to prevent spark from updating jdbc table structure)

Comment: My first comment is a deault review comment. Your answer was flagged as a low quality one due to its content and format. Edit it with the additonal explanation you provided in your comment here and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

mode(SaveMode.Append) also changing the schema based on dataframe schema , if both dataframe and oracle table schema then only it is not changing.